# Javascript prototyping forEach on Object

Tags: javascript

I want to create a prototype of forEach on objects and here is my code

```
Object.prototype.forEach = function(el,index){
    for(var k in Object){
        el = Object[k];
        index = k;
    }
}
```

Then i created an object to test this

```
var obj = {x:0,y:0,z:1290}
obj.forEach( function(el, index) {
    console.log(el+" "+index);
    alert();
});
```

This code returns no errors,but neither does it alert or log into console anything. I checked `obj` object and it does have forEach in it's `_proto_` property.I also tried

```
Object.prototype.forEach = function(el,index){
    for(var k in this){
        el = this[k];
        index = k;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a reeeeeeeeeeeeeally bad idea to change the prototype of built-in objects.

Comment: @zerkms why is it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/251311

Comment: If you want to iterate over the object properties - use `Object.entries()` or `Object.values()`.

Comment: @zerkms okay thanks for the intfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually want your function to take a function and then call that function with each element and index:

```
Object.prototype.forEach = function(f) {
    for (var k in this) {
        el = this[k];
        index = k;
        f(el, index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So Your forEach function of the object is wrong, your forEach function should take a function, you can refer to the forEach of the arrays.

```
Object.prototype.forEach = function(operation){
    for(var k in this){
        operation(this[k],k,this)
    }
}

var obj = {x:0,y:0,z:1290}

obj.forEach(function(el, index) {
     console.log(el+" "+index);
});
```